# how not going back to specific HTML page using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

so I am developing a cross platform app using phonegap\cordova and I have a page that just should be displayed once, and I used the code below to go to my next page:

```
window.location = 'htmls/menu.html';
```

I don't want this page to be displayed again but mobile back button make it navigate back to it. what should I do?

I couldn't find any thing on web. plus page I am trying not to get back to is `index.html` is that causing the problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Override `onBackpressed()` of your activity and handle back press event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to listen for the backbutton event an prevent it from working:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't work I also tried it with BackKeyDown event. but it doesn't work

Comment: do you have the cordova.js linked in your menu.html?

Comment: no it has problems with JQuery Mobile.but that is another question.

Comment: so, if you aren't using cordova, you can't use any cordova API. This code should work if you link cordova.js